# my SELECT statement is very slow

Tags: sql, performance, select, optimization, db2

My table contain 97 column with data type varchar(200) about 80% and bigint,char.

select count(*) from mytable it return
4500 rows

I am testing with 100 rows with SQL statement

select * from mytable .It use time about 2.3 min

I think,it is too very slow if return all record

please recommend me for the way to up speed my query and result.

my db server is db2 9.5

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do to improve the performance is stop using `SELECT *`. Rewrite the query to get the columns you need.

the second thing to do is to add a WHERE clause. Do you really need to return all rows for the table?

Third thing is indexes, does you table have any, can you use indexed columns in your WHERE statement, etc.

[What is the reason not to use select *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select)

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/07/18/the-real-reason-select-queries-are-bad-index-coverage.aspx

Comment: for specific column I have done.It very slow too.I need to return all rows from table 4500 record it is data from UAT  ENV.at PRD It think about 10000 rows up. my table have 1 index for data_month .

Answer (score 0):

You need to isolate what is slow, the query or displaying the query. I am assuming it is a combination of both.

When you have 97 columns each being a varchar(200) sql cannot store all the info on the same row in a [page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) . The worst case scenario is 97 * 202 (i used 202 instead of 200 because sql needs to store the length of a varchar in each column and i believe it stores it as two bytes) 19594 which is much larger than the row on a page can handle. TL;DR; normalize your table and have the columns broken up into logical units on another table.

Also doing a SELECT * FROM X will result in a full table scan which is much slower then querying on an indexed column.

If you must do a SELECT * FROM X and you have to have 97 columns please change the column data types to be a smaller data type (int,tinyint,char(10)) this will optimize the storage and should speed up the query.

Comment: i try to change data to smaller and query again it. the same result.new info for the query it return about 36 record/time.for 4500 record  use about 20 min.use toad free 4.7 free version

Comment: Will you post the table definition and query please.

Comment: @gh9 -- is your answer specific to MS SQL Server, may be? The OP indicated that he was using DB2, where you can specify the page size up to 32K.

Comment: @mustaccio -- Parts of it are, the pages and extents are specific to Sql Server. But DB2 also stores its information the same way, also the smallest data type possible for storing information applies to All databases along with the idea of Normalization

Comment: @gh my table definition you can download from here -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13792138/mytable.sql my point in mytable i use store data to prepare for report.all data in mytable i wnat to return to csv file.

Comment: I test  query data for insert to test table is very quickly to exece. INSERT INTO TEST_DATA(<MY FILED IN  MYTABLE>) SELECT <ALL COLUMN> FROM MYTABLE WITH UR;

Comment: amazing when I upload my select sql script to db server (aix) and run command db2 -tvf /home/abcadm/mysql_query.sql > /home/abcadm/mysql_query.out it use about 1s for create output file and all record return true.what's happen? I can prove that if i write into text file or table it process quckly if I query and show that via screen it process slowly by ?

Comment: @stack_none_overflow -- my GUESS is that it is not the query running slowly, it is rendering the 5k rows or however many rows you are displaying to the screen. If you aren't planning on running this manually I would do some test calls from your application and see if it runs quicker.

Comment: @gh9 what do u test about my application? It think I will use pentaho for call query. If we all delete data from table. every month we must reorg table? or do something for database process quickly.

Comment: @stack_none_overflow - I would launch your application and then time how long it takes to call your database and return data.

Comment: @gh9 about 20-30 min for 45xx records via toad 4.7 and write in csv file on db server 45xx and 11507 record about 1 s .via db2 client query not finsh i cancel it.